# Insert values in many to many relationship tables with JOOQ

Tags: java, many-to-many, jooq

I have three tables in my database, `SUBSCRIPTION`, `USER_ID`, and an association table called `SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID`.

My strategy is to use `JOOQ` batch with three queries, the first one to insert on row into `SUBSCRIPTION`, the second query to insert multiple rows into `USER_ID`, and finally, I need to insert the association IDs into `SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID`, so I did the following:

```java
InsertValuesStep2 insertUserIds = insertInto(
    USER_ID, USER_ID.USER_ID_TYPE, USER_ID.USER_ID_VALUE);

for (String userId : subscriptionDTO.getUserId())
    insertUserIds = insertUserIds.values(getValue(0, userId), getValue(1, userId));

InsertReturningStep insertReturningUserIds = insertUserIds.onConflictDoNothing();

InsertResultStep insertReturningSubscription = insertInto(SUBSCRIPTION)
        .set(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID, subscriptionDTO.getChannel())
        .set(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID, subscriptionDTO.getSenderId())
        .set(SUBSCRIPTION.CATEGORY_ID, subscriptionDTO.getCategory())
        .set(SUBSCRIPTION.TOKEN, subscriptionDTO.getToken())
        .onConflictDoNothing()
        .returningResult(SUBSCRIPTION.ID);
```

Unfortunately, to insert values into the association table, I tried many ways but nothing works for me, finally, I tried to insert values in `SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID`using with select but It doesn't work:

```java
InsertValuesStep insertValuesSubscriptionUserIds = insertInto(
        SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID, 
        SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID.SUBSCRIPTION_ID, 
        SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID.USER_ID_ID)
    .select(select(SUBSCRIPTION.ID, USER_ID.ID)
        .from(SUBSCRIPTION)
        .innerJoin(USER_ID)
        .on(concat(USER_ID.USER_ID_TYPE, 
                val(CATEGORY_USER_ID_DELIMITER), 
                USER_ID.USER_ID_VALUE).in(subscriptionDTO.getUserId())
        .and(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID.equal(subscriptionDTO.getSenderId()))
        .and(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID.equal(subscriptionDTO.getChannel()))
        .and(SUBSCRIPTION.CATEGORY.equal(subscriptionDTO.getCategory()))
        .and(SUBSCRIPTION.TOKEN.equal(subscriptionDTO.getToken()))));
```

Am I missing something above? Is there a better way using JOOQ to insert many-to-many relationship values or to use queries results as parameters for other queries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned above, I have inserted values for `SUBSCRIPTION` and `USER_ID` tables. And get for the association table I need to get the IDs of the already inserted values from the above two tables, so to solve the issue I've used this query to insert in `SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID`:

```
InsertReturningStep insertReturningSubscriptionUserId = insertInto(
    SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID.SUBSCRIPTION_ID, 
    SUBSCRIPTION_USER_ID.USER_ID_ID)
    .select(select(SUBSCRIPTION.ID, USER_ID.ID).from(SUBSCRIPTION
            .where(concat(USER_ID.USER_ID_TYPE, val(CATEGORY_USER_ID_DELIMITER), USER_ID.USER_ID_VALUE).in(subscriptionDTO.getUserId()))
            .and(SUBSCRIPTION.SENDER_ID.equal(subscriptionDTO.getSenderId()))
            .and(SUBSCRIPTION.CHANNEL_ID.equal(subscriptionDTO.getChannel()))
            .and(SUBSCRIPTION.CATEGORY.equal(subscriptionDTO.getCategory()))
            .and(SUBSCRIPTION.TOKEN.equal(subscriptionDTO.getToken()))).onConflictDoNothing();
```

Finally, I have executed all the queries using `batch`:

```
using(configuration).batch(insertReturningSubscription,
 insertReturningUserIds,
 insertReturningSubscriptionUserId).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you posted your entire code. In case of which:

#### You don't call execute on your `USER_ID` insertion

Simply add

```
insertUserIds.onConflictDoNothing().execute();
```

Or alternatively, fetch the generated IDs using a call to `returning().fetch()`

#### Inner join

This might just be a stylistic question, but what you seem to be doing is a cross join. Your `INNER JOIN` filters aren't really join predicates. I'd put them in the `WHERE` clause. Clarity may help avoid further problems in such a query.

Specifically, that first "join predicate" is very confusing, containing a `CONCAT` call, which isn't something one would see in an `INNER JOIN` every day, and only touches one table, not both:

```java
.on(concat(USER_ID.USER_ID_TYPE, 
                val(CATEGORY_USER_ID_DELIMITER), 
                USER_ID.USER_ID_VALUE).in(subscriptionDTO.getUserId())
```

#### Wrong predicate

That last predicate seems wrong. You're inserting:

```java
.set(SUBSCRIPTION.TOKEN, subscriptionDTO.getToken())
```

But you're querying

```java
.and(SUBSCRIPTION.TOKEN.equal(subscriptionDTO.getContactId()))));
```

That should probably be `subscriptionDTO.getToken()` again

Comment: Thank you. I have not posted the entire code, actually, I tried to make it simple with the necessary elements, there are more than three tables involved also, but I'm sure there is no problem with them. I'm trying to launch the queries using batch, this is why there is no call to execute in my code.
Finally, I have edited the question with the fixed predicate you mentioned.
I will try with cross join.